# Is there a problem with XeTeX font cacheing?

Tags: fonts, xetex, compiling

Here's my MWE (it's really M, as the content isn't too relevant):

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Since I migrated to TeX Live 2016 (I'm fairly certain that's when this behaviour started), this document takes some ten minutes to process.

I believe it's because XeLaTeX is rebuilding the font cache *every time it runs.*

Before this started, an occasional ....TeX run would pause for the cache rebuild, but after that, further runs of any document would go quickly.

I am not seeing this behaviour with LuaLaTeX.

Here is a piece of the TeX log file. I have inserted three exclamation points (!!!) at the exact point (as far as I can determine) at which the pause occurs:

```
Package: fontspec 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
... (fontspec macro dump)

(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX package

(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def
File: eu1enc.def 2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmr on input line 105.


(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd
File: eu1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)!!!)        <=== Here, at some point in fontenc.sty
(d:/Programs/TeX.Live/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
File: xunicode.sty 2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many
```

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Try if it helps if you run fc-cache (with or without the options -f or -r)

Comment: there's been a *very* extensive discussion about this on the tex-live mailing list -- 60 messages between last saturday (august 28) and yesterday.  i think @UlrikeFischer's comment boils it down to what was finally recommended.  (and if i understood the tex-live discussion correctly, yes, the font cache *does* get rebuilt with every xetex run if something new was added recently.  that can be co-opted by rebuilding the cache manually before launching the xetex run.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you mean that if something new is added, then, until `fc-cache` is run, XeTeX will rebuild on every compilation? But why would `fc-cache` not have been run system-wide if something new was added? I realise that stuff happens and things go wrong, but it seems weird for that many people to get bitten by something which depends on a step required for proper system configuration to be skipped.

Comment: Oh, wait ... is this on Windows?

Comment: @cfr -- windows is where the slowdown was first reported.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I always forget Windows uses this. Just it would be quite hard for me to add new fonts and avoid `fc-cache` being run. (Probably the exception is if a TeX Live update installed new TTF/OTF, but that's much less common and would be cancelled out next time any other fonts were installed or updated or whatever. And that's only an issue because I use upstream but added system integration on top. I.e. it wouldn't happen by default.) But if it is Windows, I have no idea about anything and wouldn't have commented ;).

Answer (score 2):

By experiments, I found that the renaming,

```
cachefile.NEW --> cachefile
```

almost always
fails if executed from the XeTeX binary even
in a user's writable directory.
Thus if you find a delay of time, run

```
fc-cache -v
```

If messages

```
invalid cache file: ...
```

are shown, run

```
fc-cache -v
```

once more.
It seems that this is the solution, as Ulrike stated.

Comment: I would still be very wary of setting up anything font related on a user-specific basis in TeX Live .

Answer (score 1):

I'm most grateful for all the suggestions. How I actually fixed it was thus: I deleted everything in

`(TeXLiveRoot)/texmf-var/fonts/cache`

(except `readme.txt`), and tried again.

On the first run (of course?) XeTeX rebuilt the cache; thereafter it ran normally.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Yes, I accept that. However, I did install TeX Live in Administrator mode, and for all users. On reflection, I think that may have been the source of my problem.